# What drives and/or allows the move to higher-bypass turbofans on jetliners?

Tags: commercial-aviation, jet-engine, turbofan

Note: I'm by no means an expert on any of this, I'm just curious.

There seems to be a general trend toward higher and higher bypass ratios in commercial jetliner engines. (I'm thinking here of 737/A320-size and larger aircraft.)

I understand why this is happening (fuel-efficiency & noise). But what has dictated the odd pace of the development?

There was obviously a drive toward higher bypass early on. E.g. P&W JT8D engines introduced in 1962 ran at 0.96:1, while - just a few years later in 1966 - the JT9D ran at 5:1. Quite a leap.

But then it seems to me that it settled around 5-6:1 for 25 years. Next big leap seems to be the GE90 in which runs at 9:1. That was 1992 and then it largely settled again at 9-10:1 for another couple of decades. The latest (smaller) leap appears to be the PW1000G at 12:1.

What has caused such sudden jumps and plateaus? Why hasn't there either been a more linear progression from the 1960s to now? Or a much faster progression toward the ratios we see today? They're obviously desirable.

I can just imagine P&W engineers looking at the JT9D in the mid-1960s, and thinking "well, we went from 1:1 to 5:1 in one go. Let's go for 10:1 next!". But that didn't happen. It seems their next major airliner engine was the PW2000 - fully 20 years later - at 6:1.

- Was it due to technical/manufacturing limitations?
- Has the emphasis on certain performance characteristics shifted? E.g. settling more permanently on economy over speed.
- Is it simply that fleets stabilized around certain aircraft, and no new engines were needed/wanted for a long time?

The last point seems very plausible. Even so, the 747-8, 737-MAX and A320neo, while being comparable to their ancestors in size and role, have made sudden jumps from 5-6:1 to 10-12:1 engines. That feels like something that could conceivably have happened earlier or more gradually.

Of course I know that bypass ratio isn't the *only* interesting metric for an engine, but it's a noticeable one, even to the untrained eye; engines are simply becoming bigger and bigger. But that's also why I'm asking about the pace of development, since "making the fan bigger" seems like an obvious step to take (I know there's more to it but still). It also seems like something that'd be more likely to happen gradually, rather than in spurts.

Again, I'm no expert, I've just been googling. But I may have missed something basic.

Comment: your statement about the P&W JT8D leaves me in doubt about my understanding of bypass ratio. How can it be <1:1 ?

Comment: And I also wonder why '@Flambino' keeps disappearing at the beginning of my comment... Must be a quirk of the iPad app I work with.

Comment: @RobVermeulen `How can it be <1:1?` If more air goes _through_ the core than around it. E.g. with a 5:1 engine, five times as much air goes around (bypasses) the core, as goes through it. With a 0.2:1 engine, it'd be the opposite: Five times as much air _through_, as what goes around.   And: It's not your iPad. Since you're commenting on my question, the `@flambino` part is implied: I'll see your comment automatically. You only need the @ if your comment is directed at someone other than the post's owner.

Comment: Thanks Flambino, for making me wiser on two topics at once! I failed to realize there is always air bypassing the core obviously, and that it is part of the ratio calculation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a clue look at the development in the price of oil:

[image: Historical oil price chart]

Historical oil price chart ([source](http://www.macrotrends.net/1369/crude-oil-price-history-chart))

While the first development into the 5:1 region predates the first oil crisis (1973) and was driven by fuel economy, better range and lower airport noise, the next step was kicked off by the second crisis in the early 1980s. It took one decade to develop the engines and the airplanes which could fit them, so the [Boeing 777](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777) - [GE90](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_GE90) combination came out in 1995 in a time of falling oil prices.

The next round was only kicked off after the US invasion of Iraq which made oil prices shoot up from 2003 on. Again it took a decade for the engines to become available, but now the increase in diameter is less dramatic and existing designs can be fitted with them ([A320neo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A320neo_family), [737MAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_MAX)).

Before the early 1960s the bypass ratio could not grow more because

- jet engines were developed for military aircraft, and more [emphasis was placed on top speed](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21987/why-is-the-maximum-speed-of-current-fighter-aircraft-lower-than-those-from-the-1/21988#21988) than on efficiency. Airliners used what was available (note that the [Convair 880](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_880) was powered by a simplified, non-afterburning version of the [J-79](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_J79), which powered the [F-104 Starfighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-104_Starfighter), the [F-4 Phantom II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F-4_Phantom_II) and the [B-58 Hustler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_B-58_Hustler)).
- early airliners ([De Havilland Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Comet), [Tupolev 104](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-104)) had their engines in the wing roots, so little space was available for an increased bypass ratio. When Rolls-Royce was developing the first turbofan engine, the [Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Conway), they limited the bypass ratio to 0.25 so it could fit into the Comet and the [HP Victor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handley_Page_Victor) bomber, which also had its engines in the wing roots.

The first oil crisis of 1973 kicked off the development of the unducted propfan (UDF) engine, which has been held back by noise problems. Again, it took about a decade until it could take to the air.

[image: GE36 UDF engine fitted to the MD-81]

GE36 UDF engine fitted to the MD-81 (picture [source](http://www.b-domke.de/AviationImages/Propfan/Images/MD-81_N980DC_GE36_UDF_0809.jpg))

The development of a new engine takes longer than that of an aircraft, so every time a big push, triggered by a substantial jump in oil prices, was needed to start the development of a new generation with significantly higher bypass ratio. Once the engine technology was ready and certified, it would be quickly incorporated into many models, because the better fuel economy would force everyone to upgrade.

Comment: Naturally oil price is a root cause, but I had not taken development time into account. Certainly makes sense. Likewise the part about engines evolving from military applications and their placement on the aircraft. Still, I find it funny that there hasn't been a more continuous drive toward higher bypass engines, given that better fuel efficiency and lower noise sounds like a win-win regardless of oil prices. Though I guess the same is true for cars, sadly.

Comment: @Flambino: Yes, it is a win-win, but the manufacturers first had to overcome the hurdle to start the development. This needed the pain of **much** higher oil prices. Once the engines were available, all new aircraft had to use them to stay competitive. That is why you have almost no motion and then a sudden jump.

Comment: Again: Makes a lot of sense. I just can't help but find it a strange economic artefact that engine manufacturers and/or aircraft manufacturers wouldn't make the occasional incremental change on their own. I believe the business term is "proactive". Sure, if customers _demand_ better fuel efficiency due to oil prices then it'll happen, but I could also see companies one-upping each other more regularly instead of staying in lockstep like they have.

Comment: @Flambino: Read [Dilbert](http://dilbert.com), and it should all become clear. All the companies  involved are run by managers, not far-sighted visionaries.

Comment: It's that bad, huh? Yeah, I suppose it is. It's a fun contrast to other industries, where companies routinely descend into (often ridiculous) competitions for things customers haven't really asked for (e.g. 4K TVs when there's little-to-no content for them). Not exactly visionary stuff either, but sort of the opposite result.

Comment: There's also an element of the fact that if you just upgraded to a 5:1 engine, you're not likely to be in a rush to swap that out for a 6:1 engine a year later due to the cost/benefit not lining up. Swapping that 5 years later for a 9:1, however, is a different story as you're getting more benefit and are closer to the time you'd have to replace it anyway (ie less sunk cost)

Comment: @JonStory Oh certainly (though it's more like a 25 years between swaps). That was my own theory for this; the carriers sticking to certain models of plane and powerplant, thus dictating development (or lack thereof). Makes sense for the carriers. But there are a lot of carriers - at least since the 1980s - so even if carrier A will stick to its fleet of 5:1 engines for the next decade, carrier B might be in the market for shiny new planes. So you'd think there'd be a market for a 6:1 engine, and then a 7:1, and so on. Instead everyone just buys the same stuff for 25 years - or more.

Comment: @Flambino: with consumer goods like 4k televisions it's not necessarily important that anybody has asked for it. As long as it sounds cool and prestigious, some people will get _convinced_ they want it just because it's available, even if it doesn't really make sense. Hence, offering such products means immediate financial gain for television manufacturers etc.. OTOH, if your customers are companies like airlines, every expenditure will be thoroughly checked on whether it really makes sense economically.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Oh, I know the 4K tv thing isn't a great comparison for a host of reasons. But I still find the contrast funny. For the consumer electronics it's very much "invention is the mother of necessity", and someone will always buy the latest stuff, whether or not it makes sense. And for the airline world it's exactly backwards - extremely so. It seems like everyone would _like_ to build/buy new engines more often, but it's just a stand-off instead, with both sides settling for the same stuff for decades, until something else comes along to break the stalemate.

Comment: @Flambino: The proven stuff works. If you go a new route, you have to get the new gadget certified and accepted by a skeptical workforce. When safety counts, Oh…shiny! will not be enough.

Comment: That UDF is one mean looking engine.

Comment: The Comet's wing roots weren't actually a design issue for the Rolls-Royce Conway, as the Conway-powered Comet (the Comet 5) was to have had podded engines, instead of the buried engines of the Comet 1-4.

Comment: @Sean When Conway development started, the Comet 5 was still far out in the future. Rolls-Royce could not anticipate what DeHavilland would plan a decade later. Also, the Victor was as much a reason to keep the bypass ratio down, and no podded engine version of the Victor was ever started.